# rails rendering database information in html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a simple show method that has to render all the messages in a conversation.

Everything is basic in my code, I have a show method that goes to this HTML (show.html.haml):

```
%section#list
  =  @conversation.messages.each do |message|
    .row
      = message.content
      = message.participant.user_id
```

And when I go to this show page, I have my content, but I also have a random line from the database (my HTML contains nothing else). Here is what I get :

```
This is a test 1 

[#< MyghtDefaultMessenger::Message id: 1, content: "This is a test", deleted: false, participant_id: 1, created_at: "2017-02-13 14:52:45", updated_at: "2017-02-13 14:52:45" >]
```

(I added a blank space right next to the < and > signs else SO would just render, but they aren't here in the original. [#] )

Here is my controller method in conversation_controller :

```
def show
  @conversation.messages.order(:created_at)
end
```

And the only specificity is that my conversation has many participants, my participants have many messages, and I get the messages of a conversation through participants.

Comment: Never used HAML so this is a guess. I think its because of this `=` in `=  @conversation.messages.each do |message|` . In ERB `=` is not used when you dont want to print the output of that particular ruby code, for example. `each` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `=` with `-`

- `=` prints the result of evaluated code
- `-` will just evaluate it

Change the code to

```
%section#list
  - @conversation.messages.each do |message|
    .row
      = message.content
      = message.participant.user_id
```

The second output you are getting is the result which is returned after the `@conversation.messages.each do |message|` is evaluated.

**NOTE:** Use `-` whenever you just need to evaluate for e.g. `each`, `if - else`, Assigning variable in haml

Comment: Wow thanks a lot it looks ridiculous now that you said it but when you don't know it.. thanks again